# MySQL Full text suffix search (boolean mode) -(*apple)

Tags: mysql

In boolean mode `apple*` will find `apple, apples, applestore`. But it will not find me (dummy words) `Mapple, Trapple`. So I tried using `*apple` but that doesn't work.

Is it not possible to find for words ending in apple with full text search? Or am I missing something from the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT * From Table
WHERE Word like '%apple'
```

Comment: Are you trying to tell me that there is thus no such thing available in FULL TEXT search?

Just tested '%apple' does not work, but using '%apple%' is giving an okish result for now. Will have to test some other cases though.

Comment: Im not sure if there is such a thing in FULL TEXT

Comment: @Tessmore: No, it is not possible to do suffix searches with boolean full-text searches (or, for that matter, natural language full-text searches). [The * operator *only* works for prefixes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html), as stated in the documentation on that operator.

Comment: Alright thanks for pointing that out. I think it is mostly a problem because it is about dutch language :(. I need a way to convert something like "tomatensoep" to "+tomaten +soep" so it can atleast find the soups and perhaps even some soups with tomatoes in them, but alass. Perhaps you know some direction I could look into?

(Dutch problem, since English just use spaces in between words!)

Comment: `like` work but it will slower compared to fulltext search

Answer (score 12):

Although MySQL full-text search does not allow you to search by suffixes, there's a workaround for this if you are OK with some storage overhead. You will simply need an extra column that will keep a reversed string value from the original column, and also an additional full-text index for the new column. Then your query will look in the following way:

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl
WHERE MATCH (Word_reversed) AGAINST (REVERSE('*apple') IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Remember that you will also have to maintain additional field either by means of update/insert triggers or manually.